# Whitespace at the end

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter, whitespace

I have an issue with my code, that it is printing a white space at the end. As you can see I'm not using nothing to create a white space.

my output is `2 4 10 12 39` 
and it should be `2 4 10 12 39`

```
user_input = input()
user_val = []
sort_val = 0
line = ''

for i in user_input.split():  # separates the users input
    user_val.append(int(i))  # will change all the user input to integer

user_val.sort()  # will sort the user_val from min to max

for i in user_val:
    if i >= 0:  # filter the negative numbers
        line += str(i) + ' ' # create a new line with the number and a space

print(line)
```

Comment: + ' ' adds the whitespace. Just trim the last character from the string before printing

Comment: It looks to me like you are explicitly adding a space

Comment: JJFord3 I have done that but it just put everything together.

Comment: Chris, what do you mean with explicitly adding a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point you are appending a space, you don't know yet if it is the last character. You could try initializing `line` with the first (if any) number, then appending `' ' + str(i)`. However, it would be simplest to just use `' '.join`:

```
user_input = input()
user_val = sorted(int(i) for i in user_input.split())

line = ' '.join([str(i) for i in user_val if i >= 0])

print(line)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion I copy and paste your code but I still getting the white space at the end. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The code I show can't produce a string that ends in a whitespace. I've added the rest the code you need to keep for context.